# Saving part of each line to an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to read from a file that is storing user names and addresses in the format of name:address on each new line and I wish to store only the addresses into an array. Is there any way to do this? My code currently looks like this:

```
while IFS=: read -r username address; do
   array=${address}
done <userfile.txt
```

Which is only storing the address from the first line in the file and stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right! You just need to append to the array using the `+=` operator (append) which `bash` arrays provide.

```
declare -a myArray=()
while IFS=: read -r username address; do
   myArray+=("$address")
done < userfile.txt
```

Doing the above should do the trick for you. Note that the parentheses are also critical here. `array+=(something)` appends a new element to the array, while `array+=something` just appends text to the first element of the array. Optionally later to print the array contents each in separate line use `printf` as

```
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}"
```

Comment: The parentheses are also critical here. `array+=(something)` appends a new element to the array, while `array+=something` just appends text to the first element of the array.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array+=($address)` form of adding array element.

```
array=()
while IFS=: read -r username address; do
   array+=("$address")
done < userfile.txt 
echo ${array[@]}
```